# This accident has got me a little shook up

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically correct to say "This event has got me a little shook up. ? Would it be shaken up instead of shook up.?

Comment: Presley sang [*All Shook Up*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=23zLefwiii4). I think it is used more in AmE than BrE.

Comment: See [this](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/all-shook-up). Oxford Languages doesn't say it's American. In more formal language you would say something like "This event has left me feeling shaken."

Comment: @KateBunting  that link yields an "application error" for me.

Comment: The Oxford entry says it all: This slangy idiom uses *shook* instead of the grammatically correct “shaken” (for “agitated”) and adds *all* for emphasis.

Comment: The word "got" doesn't add anything. *... has me a little shaken up...* refers to the result of the accident persisting until now. *Got* doesn't add anything. I think "shaken up" sounds better, unless you're trying to sound informal.

Comment: @GEdgar - 'This' was a link to dictionary.com.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty "The word 'got' doesn't add anything" As an American, I agree.  But note "has got" is more common in England than in the US. .... "unless you're trying to sound informal": or unless you are quoting the Elvis song.

Comment: "has gotten" would be more common than "has got" in the US. Quite informal to my ears, as earlier comments say.